# Dynamix Xpath for bounds in appium

Tags: xpath, appium

I want to create a dynamic xpath in appium to get the elements using bounds that has x coordinates 53 and varying y coordinates. This code is giving me error "Could not find function:"

`driver.findElements(By.xpath("[(contains(@bounds, '][53,'))]"));`

Answer (score 1):

Try using below code it works for me on android

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.ImageButton[@bounds='[9,288][144,318]']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the partial match working.
I'm not sure but perhaps your issue is that you are using "][53," which matches the bottom right corner x position. The code I tested with used the top left corner x and y position.

```
close_button = driver.find_element(by=AppiumBy.XPATH, value="//android.widget.ImageButton[contains(@bounds, '[78,78][') and @clickable='true']")
```

Your question actually was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I also solved this in appium (python) as follows:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH," //android.view.View[contains(@bounds, '[10,432][90,461]') and @clickable='true']").click()
```

Problem solved!!!